# Handling versioning for clients when using WCF

Tags: wcf

Desktop clients will be pushing data using WCF to a central server.

When the schema changes etc, say 100 computers have the old version of the desktop client while the rest are using the latest build.

What do I have to do on the server end to handle both versions?
Do I create 2 endpoints in WCF or a single smart endpoint that will figure out the version and act accordingly?

note: i will be passing the version info from the client (if required that is)

Answer (score 4):

You have a choice:

Firstly you should be versioning your service contracts anyway, with their namespaces; eg. `http://idunno.org/2008/10/numpty` would change to `http://idunno.org/2008/11/numpty` if the service operations have breaking changes.

Ditto with data contracts; however if all you are doing to the data contract is additive then you can mark the new fields as optional;

```
[DataMember(IsRequired="false")]
```

And old clients will work. So this should indicate to you that the parameters into a service and parameters out should also be data contracts; it gives you that flexibility.

MSDN has [more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733832.aspx)

Comment: This is a great answer, but for future searchers I just want to mention that IsRequired is actually false by default so you do not need to set it explicitly.  An important point to remember is never change the existing member's IsRequired flag from false to true, and never set new members to true! Most importantly read the MSDN link :)